# How to create a script to copy data between two table

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

I want to do a script that retrieves all the data in the table `COURBE_CHARGE` to copy them to the table with `HISTORIQUE_COURBE_CHARGE` measurement date (the field `CCH_DATE`) that is either earlier than 14 months, and that removes the copied data.

`COURBE_CHARGE` and `HISTORIQUE_COURBE_CHARGE` is the same table

*COURBE_CHARGE:*

```
Column                Data Type

CCH_ID                  NUMBER(*,0)
TLM_ID                  NUMBER(*,0)
CPT_ID                  NUMBER(*,0)
CCH_DATE                    DATE
CCH_DATE_INTEGRATION    DATE
CCH_NEW                 NUMBER(*,0)
CCH_NB_HEURES           NUMBER(*,0)
CCH_TYPE_ENERGIE            VARCHAR2(12)
P1                          NUMBER(*,0)
P2                          NUMBER(*,0)
P3                          NUMBER(*,0)
…                           NUMBER(*,0)
P149                    NUMBER(*,0)
P150                    NUMBER(*,0)
PH1                         NUMBER(*,0)
PH2                         NUMBER(*,0)
…                           NUMBER(*,0)
PH24                    NUMBER(*,0)
PH25                    NUMBER(*,0)
```

*HISTORIQUE_COURBE_CHARGE:*

```
Column                Data Type

HIS_CCH_ID                  NUMBER(*,0)
TLM_ID                  NUMBER(*,0)
CPT_ID                  NUMBER(*,0)
CCH_DATE                    DATE
CCH_DATE_INTEGRATION    DATE
CCH_NEW                 NUMBER(*,0)
CCH_NB_HEURES           NUMBER(*,0)
CCH_TYPE_ENERGIE            VARCHAR2(12)
P1                          NUMBER(*,0)
P2                          NUMBER(*,0)
P3                          NUMBER(*,0)
…                           NUMBER(*,0)
P149                    NUMBER(*,0)
P150                    NUMBER(*,0)
PH1                         NUMBER(*,0)
PH2                         NUMBER(*,0)
…                           NUMBER(*,0)
PH24                    NUMBER(*,0)
PH25                    NUMBER(*,0)
```

I have an error when i execute my script

[image: error]

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO HISTORIQUE_COURBE_CHARGE (CCH_DATE, [field list]) 
    AS 
      SELECT SYSDATE, [field list] 
        FROM COURBE_CHARGE
       WHERE CH_DATE < (SYSDATE - 425);
```

[Field list] should be expanded to the full field list of your tables. (eg. P1, P2, P3...) without the CH_DATE

The where cond: 14 months are roughly 425 days, adjust the condition if you need exactly 14 months.

EDIT: please note that ch_date will be set to SYSDATE in historical table, that can be right or wrong, depending on situation, if you need to keep track of when archiviation has been actually done (but I suggest you to add a new date column HIST_DATE and use it to store SYSDATE). In that scenario insert will be:

ALTER TABLE HISTORIQUE_COURBE_CHARGE ( ADD HIST_DATE DATE ); -- execute this only once

```
INSERT INTO HISTORIQUE_COURBE_CHARGE (HIST_DATE, [field list]) 
        AS 
          SELECT SYSDATE, [field list] 
            FROM COURBE_CHARGE
           WHERE ... -- whatever where cond
```

In this case, [field list] is the whole field list of the table. Likewise you can store other informations (such as user performing the storicization and so on).

for the deletion:

```
DELETE 
  FROM COURBE_CHARGE 
 WHERE CC_ID IN (SELECT HIS_CC_ID 
                   FROM HISTORIQUE_COURBE_CHARGE );
```

this will delete each saved row.

Comment: there is not clause Where CCH_DATE <= earlier than 14 months ?

Comment: @Mercer yes it was still in my key :( however is a trivial where condition, isn't it ?

Comment: np, however the CCH_DATE < DATEADD(MONTH, -14, SYSDATE) is more elegant

Comment: yes it is, so how can i delete my data  Once copied to my table HISTORIQUE_COURBE_CHARGE ?

Comment: a delete with the same WHERE cond. Or a DELETE querying the HIST table for presence (delete each row present in historical table, but that's possible only if you've a unique key in table)

Comment: delete with the same where cond, i have a unique key in my table CCH_ID  and HIS_CCH_ID

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO HISTORIQUE_COURBE_CHARGE
  SELECT * FROM COURBE_CHARGE
  WHERE CCH_DATE < DATEADD(MONTH, -14, SYSDATE)
```

Comment: the SELECt_INTO insert data in my HISTORIQUE_COURBE_CHARGE table ?